# How to fix time out issue with C# selenium continuous integration build on TFS server?

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, continuous-integration

I am setting up my C# selenium continuous integration build to run on TFS server

The build job has multiple stages:

1. Initialize job
2. Get sources
3. Build Solution ***.sln
4. VsTest - testAssemblies
5. Kill Stray ChromeDriver
6. Post-job: Get Sources
7. Finalize Job

All these stages passed except VsTest-test Assemblies
It always says "Build partially successed" and throws the following error

```
"##[warning]Windows Error Reporting DontShowUI not set, if the windows error dialog pops-up in the middle of UI test execution than the test will hang"
"##[error]The task has timed out."
```

I am not sure if these two errors are related or not
But it always timeout, I have tried to add TearDown method in each of my classes and it still doesn't help

```
 [TearDown]
public void BaseTearDown()
{
    driver.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you running your selenium tests using a headless browser?

Comment: No i don't thin it's headless, there are actual browser being opened on the CI server

Comment: This might be the root of your problem. When running selenium tests on a CI server, you don't get a Desktop or a window. Most CI servers block processes that require a GUI. To get around this, you can start the browser in "headless" mode so it doesn't require a GUI. Each browser vendor does it a little differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the vsTest task showing as "Partially succeeded" may due to you checked "Continue on error" option.

> **Continue on error (partially successful)**
>
> Select this option if you want subsequent tasks in the same job to
>   possibly run even if this task fails. The build or deployment will be
>   no better than partially successful. Whether subsequent tasks run
>   depends on the Run this task setting.

Please refer to this document for more info: [Task control options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#task-control-options)

Based on your warning and error,  VsTest task has a timeout option which specifies the maximum time, in minutes, that a task is allowed to execute before being canceled by server.

[image]

Change the value to 0. A zero value indicated an infinite timeout.

If you still get the same error, the time out error should be caused by the hang of your test.

For this, there are multiple reasons, make sure you have installed all and need nuget packages.

You could take a look at our official tutorial here: [UI test with Selenium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Wanted to add that if a webdriver does not exit, vstest will hang waiting for those child processes to close, and that some test failures can cause the tear-down to be skipped. I had the problem with a stack overflow in a test causing the driver to be left running and thus hanging vstest until the timeout.